# No puedo cargar un csv en jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, macos

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, en realidad tengo mucho tiempo trabajando con R y nunca me había ocurrido un problema asi.

Soy nuevo en Python y me surgió esto. Primero hice un comando sencillo

`import pandas as pd`

Después

`df=pd.read_csv('Macintosh HD⁩/Usuarios⁩/fernandoestrada⁩/Documentos⁩/experimento1.csv')`

para cargar mi archivo que se llama experimento1, intente de todo con la ruta, "cortarla" usar dos puntos antes de "/Documentos" (lo que hacia en R)
por ejemplo `df = pd.read_csv('/⁨Usuarios⁩/fernandoestrada⁩/Documentos⁩/experimento1.csv')`
pero siempre me sale este error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f580b1ac22cf> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('/⁨Usuarios⁩/fernandoestrada⁩/Documentos⁩/experimento1.csv')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427 
    428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    430 
    431     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1120     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1121         if engine == 'c':
-> 1122             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1123         else:
   1124             if engine == 'python':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1851         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1852 
-> 1853         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1854         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1855 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/\xe2\x81\xa8Usuarios\xe2\x81\xa9/fernandoestrada\xe2\x81\xa9/Documentos\xe2\x81\xa9/experimento1.csv' does not exist: b'/\xe2\x81\xa8Usuarios\xe2\x81\xa9/fernandoestrada\xe2\x81\xa9/Documentos\xe2\x81\xa9/experimento1.csv'
```

Comment: Fíjate en la última línea del mensaje de error. Allí te muestra el "verdadero" nombre de archivo que estás intentando abrir. Ves que tiene muchos bytes extra donde deberían ir los separadores de directorio. ¿Cómo has escrito la ruta al archivo? Seguramente la has copiado y pegado de algún sitio y eso te ha introducido los caracteres extra. Prueba a escribirla "a mano" tú mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias posibilidades, lo mejor es que le preguntes a Python como es que se llama la ruta de ese archivo con la siguiente línea de código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

df=pd.read_csv(file_path)
```